# PhpMailer capture email address from form and add to variable

Tags: php, forms, email, variables, phpmailer

I'm working on a site which has a form capturing name, email etc. All works fine but I would like to add a CCed email to the user who filled the form in.

I want to add the supplied email address into a varable then send them an email using AddCC as below:

```
$mail->AddCC 'test@test.com';
```

This works fine but how do I get the email address into a varable?

This php script and form are below.
Any help would be amazing,
Thanks,
James

```
//PHP

    public function SendEmail( $email_address_array, $email_data, $subject, $template, &$send_message ) {

    $smartyObj = Configurator::getInstance()->smarty;   
    $send_message = '';
    $send_result = 0;

    try { 

        $mail = new PHPMailer( true );      
        $mail->IsSMTP( true );  // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
        $mail->IsHTML( true );
        $mail->Host = Configurator::getInstance()->getSettings( "phpmailer_smtp" ); 

        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        for( $x = 0;$x < sizeof($email_address_array);$x++ ){
            $mail->AddAddress( trim($email_address_array[$x]));
        }           

        $smartyObj->assign( 'email_data', $email_data );
        $mail->SetFrom( 'info@forexchange.co.uk', 'Forexchange Currency Order');


         //  NEW TEST
        //$mail->AddCC ($usersemail);


        $mail->Subject  = $subject;
        $mail->Body     = $smartyObj->fetch( $template );           
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
        } else {
            $send_result = 1;
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $send_message = $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $send_message = $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
    //echo $send_result;
    //exit;
    return $send_result;
}
```

// FORM

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">ID Number</td>
    <td>{$email_data.id_order|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Submission Date</td>
    <td>{$email_data.cdate|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Name</td>
    <td>{$email_data.name|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Email Address</td>
    <td>{$email_data.email|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Phone</td>
    <td>{$email_data.phone|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Currency</td>
    <td>{$email_data.currency_code|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Amount</td>
    <td>{$email_data.amount|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Rate</td>
    <td>{$email_data.rate|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Pickup Point</td>
    <td>{$email_data.pickup|escape:"html"}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:15px; text-align:right;">Purchace Buy Back Product</td>
    <td>{if $email_data.purchase_buy_back_status eq '1'}Yes{else}No{/if}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Um, the HTML that you label a form isn't an HTML form, so you're not capturing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you need to use `AddCC` within `for loop` only to send email.

```
for( $x = 0;$x < sizeof($email_address_array);$x++ ){
    // Email to User
    $mail->AddAddress(trim($email_address_array[$x]));
    // Email to Admin
    $mail->AddCC(trim($email_address_array[$x]));
}
```

And, if you are passing email with `Post method` in form like `email[]` then below code will work.

```
foreach($_POST['email'] as $key => $val){
    // Check if Email coming
    echo $_POST['email'][$key];
    // Send Email Script
    $mail->AddCC(trim($_POST['email'][$key]));
}
```

Below code will extract the email from your $email_data variable that contains email content.

```
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i'‌​; 
preg_match_all($pattern, $email_data, $matches); 
$email = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not quite what I ment. I need to get the email address from the form as this is entered by the user and the data is then sent to the companys email address. I'm wanting to extract the email address from the form and then send a copy of the email to the user who typed it in. Any ideas?

Comment: You can extract with $_POST variable with foreach

Comment: foreach($_POST['email'] as $key => $val){
        // Send Email
 echo $_POST['email'][$key];
}

Comment: Check my answer now, you need to use foreach to extract all emails from $_POST

Comment: SO it would be like this?    foreach($_POST['email'] as $key => $val){ echo $_POST['email'][$key]; } 
   $mail->AddCC ($key);

Comment: AddCC will come inside loop

Comment: I'm not sure I get it! I'm really new to PHP. Do I need to add what you said into the loop and then add the other code towards to bottom to send the CCed email?

Comment: first clear me that you want to send same email to multiple users and just want one copy of cc if all multiple emails?

Comment: If sending to only one user like you are doing in your form, then no need to use for or foreach loop

Comment: So currently when the user fills in the form with data like name, phone, email, comments etc the form sends the email to an array of email addresses to the company admin. I want the email to also send a copy to the email address filled in the form. The content to both the admin and the user needs to be the same. So I think its just a case of finding the email address entered turning it into a varable and then adding that varable to the CC'ed send mail. Does that make sense? Thanks again Amit

Comment: Yes everything clear to me. That email address will come with the Post method of form like $_POST['email']

Comment: Can you tell which input name you are using in form for email?

Comment: Form that you have attached in question does not actually contains form input elements.

Comment: Should I add something to the form first, like a Class or ID?

Comment: You need to create proper form starting with <form> and ending with </form>

Comment: And add input type for all fields like name, email

Comment: <input type="text" name="Name">
<input type="text" name="Email">

Comment: Thanks Amit, Seeing that the data sent in the email already has the inputted email address in it, is there a way of extracting this email address and putting it into a varable so I dont have to mess with the HTML? Then I could send using CC with the varable maybe?

Comment: Can you send me the data coming in the email i.e. $email_data I think? Yes we can extract email from it but not that much easy.

Comment: Please send me the data coming in $email_data so that I can see and try to extract email from it.

Comment: HI Amit, the email receaved looks like this: ID Number 1881
Submission Date 2017-11-24 13:11:29
Name James Bernhard - testing
Email Address james@bernhardmedia.com

Phone 07720460007
Currency EUR
Amount 1.09
Rate 1.093
Pickup Point Cardiff Airport
Purchace Buy Back Product No

Comment: <?php 
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $email_data, $matches);
$email = $matches[0];
    ?>

Comment: James check my updated answer; I have added new code there at bottom that will extract the email from your $email_data variable.

Comment: Hope your problem will get resolve now. Please don't forget to accept my answer and upvote :)

Comment: Hi Amit, I put that script in (just above the $mail->Subject  =) and now the whole site has gone down! So removed it and tried it without the opening <php and still doesn't work.

Comment: Please add me at https://www.facebook.com/amitg100 Share with me your code there. I will sort out your issue.